# Can ring homomorphisms be characterized as ring maps such that preimage of any ideal is an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

It's a well know fact that preimage of ideals by ring homomorphism are also ideals.

Is the reciprocal true? I.e., let $f:R\to S$ be a map between the rings $R$ and $S$ s.t. $f^{-1}(I)\vartriangleleft R$ if $I\vartriangleleft S$. Then is $f$ a ring homomorphism?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. For instance, the function from any ring to itself which reverses the sign of each element (i.e. $f(x) = -x$) will conserve ideals, but it usually won't be a homomorphism.

Comment: Fantastically clear answer.  +1, using in my class.

Answer (score 12):

You can make this fail, for almost any nonzero $R$ and almost any nonzero $S$, by taking $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0,&\ x=0\\ \ \\ s_0,&\ x\ne0\end{cases}$$ where $s_0$ is a nonzero fixed element of $S$,

Then for any ideal the pre-image will be $\{0\}$ or $R$, depending on whether the ideal contains $s_0$ or not.

In some corner cases $f$ may result in an isomorphism, as Eric mentions below.

Comment: Well, not for _any_ $R$ and $S$: in some cases this $f$ will be a homomorphism, or $S$ will have no nonzero elements!

Comment: Good point. I think that it is enough to require $R,S$ to be nonzero, right? Unless you allow the zero field as the coefficients.

Comment: If $R=\mathbb{F}_2$, $s_0=1$, and $2=0$ in $S$ then $f$ will be a homomorphism.

Comment: You are right. As you see, I think in terms of complex algebras.

Answer (score 3):

Consider any bijection of $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ which isn't additive, but maps $0$ to $0$. You could, for example, take $x\neq 1$ and interchange $x$ and $1$ and map everything else to itself.

It clearly satisfies the property, since $f^{-1}(\{0\})=\{0\}$ and $f^{-1}(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$, and those are all the ideals that there are.

This map is not a ring homomorphism though, since it does not preserve the multiplicative identity.

This trick works pretty much for any map between rings, except for some edge combinations using $\{0\}$ and $F_2$.

Comment: If it is a bijection you cannot have $f(0)\neq 0$ but $f^{-1}(0)\neq 0$. In this case you actually have $f^{-1}(0)=-1$!

Comment: @Arthur doh! I better follow my own advice and pick a different bijection!

Comment: @Arthur Morning coffee is just kicking in... should be fine now.

Comment: @JoseBrox Indeed, thanks, should be fixed now.